# React Native app first shows white screen, then goes to app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am running React Native 0.56. When I start my app, it first shows a white screen for 1 second then goes to the app. My files are:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new BlurViewPackage(),
          new OrientationPackage(),
          new ReactVideoPackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo(),
          new LinearGradientPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "CONtv";
    }

    @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
        intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

and `index.js`

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

How do I make the white screen not appear? This is happening on Android.

Comment: Is this "white screen" the "Powered by React Native" screen? If so, this is expected behavior and won't happen when you install a built apk.

Comment: @IshitaSinha No it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for the white screen add a splash screen.

Check with this https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565